# Have the Document class when using CosmosDBTrigger been deprecated?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, .net-6.0, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

Have the [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.document?view=azure-dotnet) class in the `Microsoft.Azure.Documents` namespace been deprecated when developing isolated Azure functions?

I have recently migrated/upgraded a .NET6 Azure Function (v4) from running in-proccess to out-of-process a.k.a isolated (dotnet-isolated).

My Azure function is using the CosmosDBTrigger in order to act on changefeed events.

One of the required steps to migrate is to package references:

### Core packages:

> The following packages are required to run your .NET functions in an
> isolated process:

- [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker/)
- [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk/)

### Extensions packages:

> Because functions that run in a .NET isolated process use different
> binding types, they require a unique set of binding extension
> packages.

Since my Azure function uses CosmosDBTrigger I also need this package reference:

- [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.CosmosDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.CosmosDB/)

I have tested to create a new Azure Function using the .NET6 Isolated template project in Visual Studio 2022 to compare my code with the sample code. No other package references are required.

Now I can't use `IReadOnlyList<Document>` since the following old code need to be upgraded from:

```
[FunctionName("CosmosTrigger")]
    public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "ToDoItems",
        collectionName: "Items",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
        LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
        CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents,
        ILogger log)
    {
        if (documents != null && documents.Count > 0)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Documents modified: {documents.Count}");
            log.LogInformation($"First document Id: {documents[0].Id}");
        }
    }
```

To this:

```
  public class ToDoItem
  {
      public string Id { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
  }

[Function("CosmosTrigger")]
    public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "databaseName",
        containerName: "containerName",
        Connection = "CosmosDBConnectionSetting",
        LeaseContainerName = "leases",
        CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<ToDoItem> input, ILogger log)
    {
        if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
            log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].Id);
        }
    }
```

Makes no sense deserializing incoming changefeed events to a custom POCO class like `ToDoItem` as an example, the big strength with the `Document` class was the ability to deserialize the changefeed events into different custom POCO classes depending on the underlaying JSON structure of the CosmosDB document.

I'm not sure how to handle future breaking changes to my CosmosDB documents, currently we have a documentVersion property containing a integer value in order to deserialize the changefeed events into the correct custom POCO class.

The example code above would cause a runtime exception if deserializing JSON not mathing the data structure of the `ToDoItem` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, seems like you are using the 4.0.0-preview Extension, keep in mind this is a **preview** extension, not meant for production.

Deserializing to a custom POCO has been a big ask for a lot of customers. Having to pay the performance cost of going from `Document` to a business class was not ideal for many people. It does make sense to give people the freedom to remove double serialization from their workflows.

If what you want is to have a generic class to deserialize to, you can follow the [V3 migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/migrate-dotnet-v3?tabs=dotnet-v3#classes-replaced-on-net-v3-sdk) and a good replacement for `Document` is `JObject`. Or if you are using `System.Text.Json` [as serialization engine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71243311/5641598), `JsonDocument`.

Comment: Thanks using JsonDocument might be a good alternative. I agree with you regarding the performance cost of double serialization, but I want to make sure I can handle CosmosDB documents with breaking changes in the JSON structure without causing runtime exceptions. I recently learned about the "new" retry policies by Microsoft using the ExponentialBackoffRetry attribute, using infinite retries this kind of runtime exceptions occur might be a good solution, to make sure any changefeed events are lost due to updated lease checkpoint.

Comment: If you decide to use JsonDocument remember you need to change the serialization engine to System.Text.Json, otherwise the default uses Newtonsoft.Json and JObject would be the right type.

Answer (score 1):

`JsonDocument` also didnt worked for me. I used `string` instead of `IReadOnlyList<Document>` and cast it to my document object model.

```
    [FunctionName("CosmosTrigger")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "ToDoItems",
            collectionName: "Items",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)] string documentsJson,
            ILogger log)
{
  var documents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable</*MyDocumentModel*/>>(documentsJson);
  if (documents != null && documents.Count > 0)
   {
     log.LogInformation($"Documents modified: {documents.Count}");
     log.LogInformation($"First document Id: {documents[0].Id}");
   }
}
```